# Not Equal Condition not working (JS)

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Why does my alert always shows up whith the following code :

```js
var choix = "a";
while (choix.toUpperCase() !== "Q") {
  choix = prompt(hello + "\n");
  if((choix.toUpperCase() !== "A") || (choix.toUpperCase() !== "L") || (choix.toUpperCase() !== "Q")) {
    alert("Choisissez L, A ou Q !");
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `||` in `if` statement.

Comment: Sure, i was really stupid on that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `&&` instead of `||`.

Personally, I would rewrite the code as:

```
var choix;

while (true) {
  choix = prompt("hello\n");
  if (["A", "L", "Q"].contains(choix.toUpperCase())) break;
  alert("Choisissez L, A ou Q !");
}
```

Comment: @Kyll duly noted sir. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
choix = prompt('hello' + "\n");
```

According to your code I can not run, you may be wrong syntax, and you try to change the phrase

Comment: i've a variable named hello

Answer (score -1):

```
prompt(text,defaultText)
```

Your input=>

```
choix = prompt(hello + "\n");
```

is wrong, you should enter a string

```
choix = prompt('hello' + "\n");
```

```js
var choix = "a";
  while (choix.toUpperCase() !== "Q") {
   choix = prompt('hello' + "\n");
   if ((choix.toUpperCase() !== "A") || (choix.toUpperCase() !== "L") || (choix.toUpperCase() !== "Q")) {
    alert("Choisissez L, A ou Q !");
   }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't paste my entire code, i have a variable whose name is hello